# Nautilus in Gnome 3: delete key is not working

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, nautilus

I just installed a fresh **Debian 8** with **Gnome 3** and in **Nautilus** the **delete key is not working**.

Via Google I found out that setting `org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels` to `true` with dconf should be a workaround allowing to reassign the hotkey for the Nautilus action *move to trash*. Unfortunately this is not working for me.

Another solution suggested setting

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "<Primary>Delete")
```

to

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "Delete")
```

in the config file `~/.config/nautilus/accels`.

Even after a refresh (`Alt+F2` and then `r`) plus closing all Nautilus instances and reopening nautilus this did not work either.

Is this a known problem? Are there any other possible solutions?

**EDIT:** don_crissti stated that `accels` are **broken** since Gnome **3.12** <del>and until **< 3.16**</del>. So the only option left seems to be waiting <del>for Gnome >= 3.16 to be integrated or updating manually</del>.

Comment: No, you got it wrong... `accels` are broken, even in current `3.18` (as a result you can not customize shortcuts). The other thing (the `delete` key that is supposed to _delete_ stuff when you press it) is fixed in 3.16. Not the `accels` though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the default keyboard shortcut for deletion, which is `ctrl+del`.

Comment: Yeah... this only applies to gnome < 3.16 (as of 3.16 they finally fixed this nonsense)

Comment: So? Debian Jessie has 3.14, right?

Comment: I don't know as I don't use debian, my comment was for future visitors...

Comment: Thanks for the post & yep, I am using this "hotfix" but my intention was to retrieve the original behaviour. Any ideas how the shortcut could be changed or why altering `~/.config/nautilus/accels` seems to have no effect?

Comment: @ascenator - _accels_ are currently broken (they no longer work in gnome 3.12 and later IIRC). The best way (definitely not the easiest) is to patch the source code and rebuild `nautilus` ([this gentoo patch](https://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/gnome-base/nautilus/files/nautilus-3.5.91-delete.patch?revision=1.1) should get you started). Or wait until `3.16` is available in your distro repository.